# Fast gradient sign method

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

In [Explaining and Harnessing Adversarial Examples](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6572.pdf), Goodfellow et. al. present the fast gradient sign method of adversarial attack. Namely,

$$
\tilde{x} = x + \epsilon \text{sign}( \nabla_x J(\theta, x, y) )
$$

In explaining the application of this technique to a simple logistic model in Section 5, it is stated that

> Note that the sign of the gradient is just $− \text{sign}(w)$

Apart from what appears to be a mix of variables between $\theta$ and $w$ for model parameters, I'm confused as to why the statement above is true. The loss function, as introduced in the paper, is

$$
J = \zeta \left( -y (w^\top x + b) \right)
$$

where $y \in \{-1, 1\}$ denotes ground-truth labels and $\zeta(z) = \log(1 + e^z)$ is the softplus function. Using chain rule, and possibly with a slight abuse of notation, we know that

$$
\nabla_x J = \frac{dJ}{dz} \frac{dz}{dx}
$$

where $z = -y(w^\top x + b)$.

Since the softplus function is monotonically increasing, its derivative will always be positive. Thus, the first term in the chain rule can be dropped when considering only the sign of the terms.

$$
\begin{align}
\text{sign}(\nabla_x J) 
&= \text{sign} \left( \frac{dJ}{dz} \frac{dz}{dx} \right) \\
&= \text{sign} \left( \frac{dz}{dx} \right) \\
&= \text{sign} \left( -y w \right)
\end{align}
$$

Given that $y$ can either be 1 or -1, doesn't this suggest that the sign of the gradient is not always the negative of the sign of $w$?

I appreciate your help!